# Using the vSphere SDK to run a script on a host

Tags: vmware

I've written applications making use of the vCloud SDK in the past, and it provided the ability to provide a guest customization script that would be run on the VM when you provisioned. This let me automate VM provisioning from code along with a few per-host customizations, which was great. Since these VMs were running on ESXi, this told me that passing in a script to be run on the VM was a capability of ESXi and the VMWare Tools.

Now I'm working with the vSphere SDK, and I can't a similar capability anywhere. I want to be able to provide a script to my hosts that joins them to my domain, but I can't figure a way to pass a script that does this from the SDK. Is this possible? Or is this capability somehow unique to vCloud?